# Array length is undefined when stored in variable

Tags: javascript, arrays

In the following [w3schools example](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp) - why does this return 3

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var cars = [
    "Saab",
    "Volvo",
    "BMW"
];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = cars.length; //returns 3

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and when I try to store cars.length in a variable it returns undefined?

```
var test = cars.lenght;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = test; // returns undefined
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have spelling mistake

```
 var test = cars.length;
```

Comment: Or maybe he didn't defined `cars`

Comment: no that did the trick! damn i tried it at least 10 times and always spelled it wrong ...

Comment: You might find this helpful if you are using Sublime Text :)

https://github.com/jpallister/Sublime-Text-AutoCorrect-Plugin

Answer (score 1):

```
cars.lenght
```

???

"lenght" != "length"

Answer (score 0):

Typo mistake. You have undefined property (`lenght`) to access the length property of your array. You should instead use

`cars.length`

which gives you the length of the array cars - 3. So var test will have 3 assigned to it.

Answer (score -1):

Obviously, `cars.length` returns `3` because we are trying to get the length of array.

```
function myFunction() {
var index;
var text = "<ul>";
var cars= [
  "Saab",
  "Volvo",
  "BMW"];
for (index = 0; index < cars.length; index++) {
    text += "<li>" + cars[index] + "</li>";
}
text += "</ul>";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

check `for` loop in the above example it uses `index < cars.length`

**Output of above code will be**

- Saab
- Volvo
- BMW